# Dynamically highlight a list item without highlighting its children

Tags: jquery, css, focus, background-color, html-lists

It seems that similar questions have been asked, but they don't quite fit what I'm trying to do.

I am making a keyboard accessible tree widget. Whichever list item is selected should have a background color applied to it, but I don't want that background color applied to its children. How do I do this? Here's what I have now:

```
// javascript
$(rootLi).focus(function(event) {
    $(this).addClass('focusNode');
});

// css
.focusNode {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

But then all the children are orange. I also tried applying the background color to the `span` that contains the display text for the `li`, but when I do that, all of the `span` elements in the nested tree get highlighted too.

I admit I'm pretty weak with my CSS. Can someone advise? Thanks!

**Edit**

I've been asked to post the HTML. I think my problem is pretty straightforward, but I guess it can't hurt :)

```
  <div id="treewidget">
    <ul role="tree" aria-activedescendant="rootItem" tabindex="0">
      <li id="rootItem" tabindex="0" role="treeItem" data-id="1" aria-expanded="true"
      aria-labelledby="contentFor1">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="expanded"></a> <span id=
        "contentFor1">foo</span>

        <ul role="group">
          <li tabindex="0" role="treeItem" data-id="2" aria-expanded="true"
          aria-labelledby="contentFor2"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class=
          "expanded"></a><span id="contentFor2">bar</span></li>

          <li tabindex="0" role="treeItem" data-id="3" aria-expanded="true"
          aria-labelledby="contentFor3"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class=
          "expanded"></a><span id="contentFor3">baz</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please post the HTML also. It is very hard to help otherwise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resetting the bg color on the sub trees should work

```
// css
.focusNode ul {
    background-color: white; // original color
}
```

Here is a simplified fiddle on it http://jsfiddle.net/uFaUS/2/

This is more css rules than an issue with jQuery, the focus node wraps around the sub items.

Comment: +1. The root LI contains the children LI. So it makes a box around them. Turn on a border and you will see this. So when you make it orange, the orange shows through the children. As William points out, setting the child UL to have a white background solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without the code I can only guess but it looks like the children of `li` you want to highlight don't have background specified, so their background is in fact transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the class to the first child span tag? It'd be something like this:

```
$(this).children("span").first().addClass("focusNode");
```